# Is it possible to set service with dots, dashes in docker swarm

Tags: docker-compose

I have a hostname with dots and dashes. I need to use that hostname as the service name.

Suppose My hostname is `Prasanna.abc.in`. I want to make that hostname as a service name in the docker stack file.

Answer (score 1):

Docker allows you to create a service with a "DNS name component". That's alpha numeric with dashes, and up to 63 characters. [See the hostname spec on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname). This does not let you use underscores or dots in the name since that is not a hostname component (dots are used to separate multiple components and underscores would be invalid).

For a FQDN, consider using a label on your service instead. You'll be able to give that label the full value of the hostname, and query by that label.